# populate lable control inside a gridview based on inline Conditional statement

Tags: asp.net, gridview, inline-code

I am trying to display a plain text in the column(contains a label) of gridview based on  a condition. Here is my erroneous code. Please correct.

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblAsgn" runat="server"   Text= '<%#Eval("StatusId") == 0 ? "NEW" : "OLD" %>' > </asp:Label>
```

Thanks in advance.

BB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<asp:Label 
    ID="lblAsgn" 
    runat="server"   
    Text='<%# FormatText(Eval("StatusId")) %>' />
```

where `FormatText` could be a method in your code behind:

```
protected string FormatText(object o)
{
    int value;
    if (int.Parse(o as string, out value) && value == 0)
    {
        return "NEW";
    }
    return "OLD";
}
```

Comment: I get the following error at the if statement The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(String,System.IFormatProvider) has some invalid arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblAsgn" runat="server"   Text= '<%# Eval("StatusId").Equals(0) ? "NEW" : "OLD" %>' > </asp:Label>
```